# How to access items within a collection map without breaking a fluent chain?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

If you have a simple `map` using the Laravel collection, you can easily access the base collection by doing the following:

```
$items = [ "dog", "cat", "unicorn" ];
collect($items)->map(function($item) use ($items) {
    d($items); // Correctly outputs $items array
});
```

If using a fluent chain with filters / rejections, $items no longer represents the set of items:

```
$items = [ "dog", "cat", "unicorn" ];
collect($items)
    ->reject(function($item) {
        // Reject cats, because they are most likely evil
        return $item == 'cat'; 
    })->map(function($item) use ($items) {
        // Incorrectly (and obviously) outputs $items array (including "cat");
        // Would like to see the $items (['dog', 'unicorn']) here
        d($items);

        // Will correctly dump 'dog' on iteration 0, and 
        // will correctly dump 'unicorn' on iteration 1 
        d($item); 
    });
```

**Question**

Is it possible to access either the modified items array, or alternatively, get access to the collection in its current state.

Similar libraries in Javascript, like lodash, pass in the collection as the third argument - the Laravel collection does not.

**Update/Edit**

To be clear, I can do something like (but it breaks the chain). I would like to do the following, but without the inbetween storage of the collection.

```
    $items = [ "dog", "cat", "unicorn" ];
    $items = collect($items)
        ->reject(function($item) {
            // Reject cats, because they are most likely evil
            return $item == 'cat'; 
        });

    $items->map(function($item) use ($items) {
            // This will work (because I have reassigned 
            // the rejected sub collection to $items above)
            d($items);

            // Will correctly dump 'dog' on iteration 0, and 
            // will correctly dump 'unicorn' on iteration 1 
           d($item); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `d($items);` inside `map()` it refers to your original array. If you do `var_dump($item)` inside `map()` you'll see that it outputs only *dog* and *unicorn*.

```
$items = [ "dog", "cat", "unicorn" ];
$newItems = collect($items)
    ->reject(function($item) {
        // Reject cats, because they are most likely evil
        return $item == 'cat';
    })->map(function($item) use ($items) {
        var_dump( $item );//TODO
    });

var_dump( $newItems );//TODO
```

Comment: I perhaps wasn't clear - I will update the question. I am looking to access the *whole*, and possibly reduced, collection within each iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current state of the collection by running something like `$this->all()`.

```
$items = collect(["dog", "cat", "unicorn"])
    ->reject(function($item) {
        return $item == 'cat'; 
    })
    ->map(function($item) {
        dd($item); // current item (dog/unicorn);
        dd($this->all()); // all items in the collection (dog and unicorn);
    });
```

Comment: Are you _sure_? `$this` refers to the current object/instance (which yes, has access to `items`) however, $items will still be the original unmodified version. Thats my understanding anyway

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Since Laravel collections are immutable, `$this` refers to a collection that (in this case) does not contain 'cat' as it was rejected in the operation above. `$items` variable points to a collection that is the result of all operation in the collection pipeline.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but `$this` refers to the current context - for example: https://gist.github.com/cjke/fa0e152b5d57da41e74e5027446984d4  `$this` will refer to the `RouteServiceProvider`

Comment: Oh yeah. That's my mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

you can do it something like this way.

```
  return collect($models->items())->each(function ($item, $index){
        if( !$item->quoteReturnDetail){  echo  $item ;  exit(); }   });
```